# Cython: ImportError: No module named 'myModule': how to call a cython module containing a cimport to another cython nodule?

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to import a cython module data.pyx into another cython module user.pyx.
Everything compile fine, but when I try to call user.pyx in a python module, I am getting the error 'ImportError: No module named data'.

Everything is in the same directory.

```
package/
    __init__.py   #empty
    setup.py      
    data.pxd
    data.pyx
    user.pyx
```

My setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext


ext_modules = [
    Extension("data", ["data.pyx"]),
    Extension("user", ["user.pyx"],include_dirs = ['myPackageDir'])
    ]

setup(
  name = 'app',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules  
)
```

Running the following test.py will raised the error.

```
import user     #this line raised the 'ImportError: No module named data' below
user.doSomething()
```

The exception I get is

```
Traceback:
 File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import package.user
  File "user.pyx", line 1, in init user (user.c:3384)
ImportError: No module named data
```

How can I make the import work? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why did you edit your code to the working code when it should actually demonstrate the wrong code?

Comment: @Niklas I see your point. With my edit, the post becomes confusing. Rob post solves the error 'ImportError: no module named user'. But My actual problem was the error 'ImportError no module named _data_', which I solved by recompiling all my project. As Rob post solves a real potential problem, I marked it as answer, even if it was not my actual problem. Sorry, for the confusion. If there is a better way, please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be missing something about Cython, but I think it's:

```
import package.user
user.doSomething()
```

Comment: My mistake, in my code I wrote 'package.user' as you suggest. But I forgot to typed it when writing my question. I've corrected my question.

Comment: I rebuilt every file in my project and it has fix the problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're certainly welcome, but it sounds like you fixed the problem yourself.  Glad it's working!

Answer (score 19):

I encounter this problem again in an another project. To solve it, here is what I did:

- all `import` and `cimport` statement must be fully qualified
- all the python code must be contained in a `rootFolder`
- the `setup.py` must be at the same level than the `rootFolder`
- all folder in the `rooFolder` including the `rootFolder` must contains a `__init__.py`
- in your `setup.py` the extension's `include_dirs` must contains `'.'`

I created a simple project which illustrates this [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cython-users/6trL0V1bLx4/7bxhj0xCK50J).
This [page](http://wiki.cython.org/PackageHierarchy) helped me created it.
But my project is simpler and I think it would have helped me a lot if I had it.
My project also illustrate how to automatically build all cython files in a project.

Comment: Does anyone happen to have a Python 3 example of the simple project?

Comment: Hi, why don't you put on the github?

Comment: "in your setup.py the extension's include_dirs must contain '.'"
This solved a problem which I had been having for about 2 years. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PDiracDelta that magically solved an issue of mine as well.  This is insane.  Why can't they fix it?

Comment: This answer is sadly true.  You simply cannot do sibling side-by-side cython packages to be modular.   Or they don't make it easy.

Comment: I ran into this today. It seems that Cython expects the project to be structured like a Python package and each module to be compiled separately into a separate extension. This makes sense since it needs to adhere to Python's import system for it all to work, which uses the file system to define the package and modules. Wish it was documented a little better though.