# How to correctly make a python package?

Tags: python, package

This is my first time making a python package, and I am thoroughly confused about `__init__.py`, `__main__.py`, and their relation to making a package.

Here is my project structure:

```
package_name/
    setup.py
    README.md
    LICENSE
    package_name/
        __init__.py
        __main__.py
        A.py
        B.py
```

Class A in `A.py` depends on a class B in `B.py`.

Should I have both `__init__.py` and `__main__.py`?
What should be in the files?

What I have tried:

in `A.py`:

`from B import B` and `from .B import B`

The first allows me to run normally locally, but when I try to upload it to pypi and install it, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'B'`

The second allows me to import it after installing it from pypi, but I can't run it normal locally.

My goal is to import Class A from the package with the following

```
from package_name import A
```

and be able to run my package locally.

Edit:
I am using Python 3.

Comment: Are you using python 3 or 2? Usually you don't need to include `__main__.py` in either, that's for more specific needs.

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'B'` means that your `B.py` is not found in `syspath`. You can try to manually add  it during runtime in `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files named init.py are used to mark directories on disk as a Python package directories, you can let this empty most of the time. 
But let's say you have for example this file structure with the following code inside them:

**Structure**

```
    package_name/
    ├── setup.py
    ├── package_name
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── main.py
    └── package_name.py
```

**setup.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name = "package_name",        
    version = "0.1",
    packages=["package_name"],   
    package_data = {},
    author="xxx",
    author_email = "xxx@xxx.xx",
    description = "The familiar example program in Python",
    license = "BSD",
    keywords= "example documentation tutorial",
)
```

**package_name.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import package_name.main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(package_name.main.main())
```

**main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

def main(argv=None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv

    print("Hello, world")

    return 0
```

Go in the terminal to the package_name folder and type: "python3 package_name.py" to execute the code.

**Output**

```
Hello, world
```

The package.py goes to the main.py and execute the code that is in the main.py. If you want to import in your example try using for example "`from package_name.A.py import [function name]`" in the the python files you wish to access the functions. It should work.

Comment: I looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882447/cython-importerror-no-module-named-mymodule-how-to-call-a-cython-module-con and it seemed to explain too