# cython: Building a multi-package project and using it as a submodule of another python package

Tags: import, cython

I'm pretty new to cython and quite confused by the differences between cimport and import, they do not seem to behave the same way.

I have a cython project that contains two different cython modules:

```
test_cython
+ test
| + __init__.py
| + bar.pxd
| + bar.pyx
| + foo.pyx
+ setup.py
```

**init**.py

```
from .foo import *
```

bar.pxd

```
cdef class Bar:
    cdef get_name(self)
```

bar.pyx

```
cdef class Bar:
    cdef get_name(self):
        return "Hello from Bar"
```

foo.pyx

```
from .bar cimport Bar

def hello():
    return Bar().get_name()
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension('test.foo', ['test/foo.pyx']),
    Extension('test.bar', ['test/bar.pyx']),
]

setup(
    name='Test',
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
    include_dirs=["test"],
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
)
```

I run my test code with this:

```
>>> import test
>>> test.hello()
'Hello from bar'
```

When I compile and run this project, everything works fine. But if I then try to use it as a submodule of another project by copying `test` to a python project like `otherProject`, and then running

```
>>> from otherProject import test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\path\to\otherProject\test\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .foo import *
  File "test\foo.pyx", line 1, in init test.foo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.bar'
```

This was working when having only one cython module, so it seems to be related to `cimport`. It is also working when using the same pattern with pure python packages. My guess is that since the package needs to be fully qualified, the relative import doesn't really work, and `test.bar` cannot be a subpackage.

I'm trying to see if there could be a way to build the cython modules without them being fully qualified, but the multiple posts I've seen about this require the cython modules to be fully qualified.

For instance:
[Cython: ImportError: No module named 'myModule': how to call a cython module containing a cimport to another cython nodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882447/cython-importerror-no-module-named-mymodule-how-to-call-a-cython-module-con)

Comment: If you use relative import, your cython-code should be probably cythonized with language_level=3, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/54900723/5769463

Comment: Yeah I also tried with this, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: When you write an extension class methods declared as `cdef` will only be accessible by Cython code. You need to either use regular `def` (always slower, Python calls) or `cpdef` (slower Python calls if called from Python, faster C calls if called from Cython).

Comment: Relevant docs: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html